# Dropzone Display Error Message

Tags: jquery, json, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js, which is uploading fine. However when uploading multiple images, all images are coming up with the green tick, even though my json result is bringing back "Error in saving file".

My question is, and I have searched high and low for an answer, how to I change that tick to a "X" and display the error message?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
        init: function() {
            this.on("complete", function(data) {
                var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);

                if (res.message == "Error in saving file") {

                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: what status code are you sending back?

Comment: In my function, I am sending back "message". I can send back any status code depending on any specific error I want to log.

I just need to get <div class="dz-error-mark"> and <div class="dz-error-message"> showing really.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: i would try to send a non-HTTP 2xx back to the client from the server. that way the XHRs will know something went wrong.